# Programmatically set a TextField's value while in ReadOnly mode?

Tags: java, vaadin

Vaadin widgets offer `setEnabled` and [`setReadOnly`](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractField.html#setReadOnly(boolean)) methods. I want the visual black color readability of the read-only state rather than greyed-out disabled state. My goal is to prevent the user from making direct data entry.

Unfortunately, the read-only mode on a TextField not only prevents the user from data entry. It also prevents me from programmatically setting the value with a call to `setValue`.

The workaround is to have my code (1) Call setReadOnly with False, (2) Call setValue, (3) call setReadOnly with True.

> ➤ Is there a simpler way to change the value of a TextField while in read-only mode?

Comment: I didn't found better solution how to put value in the Vaadin TextField, which is read only, programmatically. But this solution works properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a simpler way to change value of a `TextField` in read-only mode, if you go through the source code for `AbstractField` `setValue` method, you can discover that.

But you still can do that on your own using simple function like:

```
 public void setValue(TextField textField, String value) {
          if (textField.isReadOnly()) {
              textField.setReadOnly(false);
              textField.setValue(value);
              textField.setReadOnly(true);
          } else {
              textField.setValue(value);
          }
    }
```

Comment: It would be good to set the value in a try-finally-block and re-setting the readOnly property in the finally part.

Comment: @nexus I don't understand exactly what do you want to do, but generally `try-catch-finally` block is much more expensive than simple condition if statements.

Comment: try { textField.setValue(value); } finally { textField.setReadOnly(true); } so whatever happens in setValue() in the end the textField will be read-only

Comment: @nexus this won't solve the problem, if `textField` is set to readonly, then `try { textField.setValue(value); }` will raise an exception and won't set the value, then the finally clause won't be useful anyway, because it is already readonly, and if the `textField` is not readonly, then finally clause will set it to readonly which not logical.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the disabled color instead.

```
input[disabled], .v-disabled {
    color: #22222;
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```